# How to infer method signature of generic delegate type to call a list of delegates

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an event handler that will loop through a list of delegates of the same type and invoke them if needed.  What I ultimately want is a "master" handler that controls which child handlers get called (this is for a nested state machine that implements default event handling, so if the event gets handled in a nested level stop it from propagating up to the higher levels)

My simplest solution was to only subscribe the "deepest" event handler.  But this isn't really the behavior I want, I want the body of that handler to say whether it actually "handled" the event or not, if it didn't then call the next level up.

So my second approach is to have only one actual subscriber to the event.  This in turn steps through a list of delegates and invokes them with a modified method signature that returns a boolean if it handled the event.

My .NET event definition:

```
        public static event SensorChangeHandler SensorChangedEvent;
        public delegate void SensorChangeHandler(bool triggered);
        public static void TriggerSensorChange(bool triggered)
        {
            SensorChangedEvent?.Invoke(triggered);
        }
```

In my "master handler" class:

```
        List<Func<bool, bool>> myChildHandlers = new List<Func<bool, bool>>();
        public void AddChildHandler(Func<bool, bool> childHandler)
        {
            myChildHandlers.Add(childHandler);
        }

        public SensorChangeHandler GetMasterHandler()
        {
            return (bool sensorTriggered) =>
            {
                foreach(var handler in myChildHandlers)
                {
                    if(handler(sensorTriggered))
                    {
                        // event handled, so break out of loop
                        return;
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

In my calling class:

```
            MasterHandler sensorChangedMaster = new MasterHandler();
            sensorChangedMaster.AddChildHandler((bool triggered) =>
            {
                if(triggered)
                {
                    // do some stuff
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // not handled
                    return false;
                }
            })
            // the actual .NET event subscriber
            SensorChangedEvent += sensorChangedMaster.GetMasterHandler();
```

This works fine if all I want to do is respond to SensorChanged events.  But I'd like to make this pattern work generically, i.e.

```
MasterHandler sensorChanged = new MasterHandler<SensorChangeHandler>();
```

and

```
public class MasterHandler<THandler> {
...
        List<Func<bool, THandlerArgs>> myChildHandlers = new List<Func<bool, THandlerArgs>>();
        public void AddChildHandler(Func<bool, THandlerArgs> childHandler)
        {
            myChildHandlers.Add(childHandler);
        }

        public THandler GetMasterHandler()
        {
            return (THandlerArgs args) =>
            {
                foreach(var handler in myChildHandlers)
                {
                    if(handler(args))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            };
        }
}
```

I'm new to working with generics and reflection, and it's not clear to me how to get the delegate arguments and pass them to the handlers.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you're describing sounds like chain of responsibility. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635857/c-sharp-chain-of-responsibility-with-delegates

Comment: Can you explain why you are not using the `add` and `remove` event accessors to implement this pattern? (I don't understand why you're doing this work at all, but if you are going to do it, it seems perverse to work around all the gear we put into the language to help you do it.)

Comment: I like the chain of responsibility, thanks for the link!  That does sound like what I'm trying to accomplish.  @EricLippert This is a learning exercise for me, I wanted to try to implement a statemachine framework that fits in well with .NETs events.  I'm new to C# so not really sure how changing the add and remove accessors would help me.  My reason for having a separate AddChildHandler method is I don't actually want to subscribe to the event, but rather call manually in the delegate returned by GetMasterHandler().  I agree its funky so I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 1):

When you have a single publisher and multiple subscribers, the standard way to allow communication between subscribers is to provide a boolean property `Handled` in your `SensorChangedEventArgs` class. This way one subscriber would handle the event, set the `Handled` property to true, and all the other subscribers would see that the event is handled and exit without doing anything else.

In your case it seems that you have multiple publishers and one subscriber, so the situation is different. Honestly your architecture is quite confusing to me.

Comment: Haha its confusing to me too.  I'm still trying to do a single publisher multiple subscribers architecture, but the multiple subscribers would go through a single actual (in terms of .NET events) subscriber to the event.  Question, how does changing the event args allow other subscribers to see the changed property?  Are you saying you would pass the args by reference?  Also, I don't want to have to change the event delegate signature to fit any specific "handled" pattern.

Comment: The EventArgs is an object, and the same object is passed to all subscribers of the event. So it becomes a shared state for the subscribers.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that.  That could be a good solution if I can enforce that all events that my statemachine has the same Handled property.  I was hoping to not touch the delegates so I could extend usage to e.g. winforms events without having to put a wrapper around them

Comment: For maximum compatibility your SensorChangedEventArgs should inherit from EventArgs.